# How to stop FluentPDO incorrectly inferring a table name

Tags: php, mysql, fluentpdo

I have a table of users, and I want to be able to filter the table by the email column, so I can see all the users with 'gmail.com' accounts, for example.

My current fpdo query looks like this:

```
$filter_email = trim($_GET['email']);
$fpdo->from('users')
    ->where('users.email LIKE "%' . $filter_email . '%"')
    ->fetchAll();
```

When I set `$filter_email` to **a@b**, everything works fine, and FluentPDO generates this SQL statement:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
WHERE users.email LIKE "%a@b%"
```

But if I search for **a@b.c** FluentPDO tries to find the table `b` and errors

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = users.b_id
WHERE users.email LIKE "%a@b.c%"
```

I don't know how FluentPDO sees `b.c` as a table to join on, or how to stop it.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks mostly to deceze and also to aynber, here's the working solution:

```
$filter_email = '%'.trim($_GET['email']).'%';
$fpdo->from('users')
    ->where('users.email LIKE ?',$filter_email)
    ->fetchAll();
```

My actual query checks three different email fields, but using three `?` and appending `$filter_email` three times works just fine:

```
->where(
    '(users.email1 LIKE ? OR users.email2 LIKE ? OR users.email1 LIKE ?)',
    $filter_email,
    $filter_email,
    $filter_email
)
```

Comment: It would probably stop doing that if you passed the value using parameter binding, **which would also prevent the SQL injection vulnerability you have.** Not being familiar with FluentPDO I can't tell you how to do that, but this code as is should never reach production either way.

Comment: @HankyPanky MySQL doesn't really care about single vs double quotes as long as you're consistent. Other databases do, apparently. However, parameter binding will quote it properly.

Comment: @aynber If you're using database-native parameter binding, it won't quote it at all, since it's never interpolated into the query string but sent as a separate value.

Comment: @HankyPanky I've never had an issue with single vs double quotes. Apparently, though, if you have `ANSI_QUOTES` turned on, you might see some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its (apparently not so) "smart join builder" probably sees the `.` and thinks it relates to another table. You might want to file a bug with the author.

However, **you're vulnerable to SQL injection** concatenating the input directly into the query like that. Solving that will probably also solve your join issue. Quickly looking over the [documentation](https://github.com/fpdo/fluentpdo), the parameter binding syntax looks like it should be this:

```
$fpdo->from('users')
     ->where('users.email LIKE ?', '%' . trim($_GET['email']) . '%')
     ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: The correct way is `->where("users.email LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')")`, and the same approach can be used with regular `PDO` as well. No issues will ever arise.

Comment: Thanks deceze. I've been working on some other filter queries, and realised I could use the `?` token. Then the SQL injection worry dawned on me.

Comment: @Mjh Why is a concat within SQL better than a concat within PHP?

Comment: @Stuart Not *could*, ***must***.

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious? The two are doing different things.

Comment: @Mjh No, the answer is not obvious. I am passing the value `'%foo%'` to the database; you are just passing `'foo'` and are asking the database to concat that into `'%foo%'` itself. I don't know why you think that's better or more correct.

Comment: Because using my suggestion, underlying engine can properly quote the value automatically. Using your suggestion, you must quote the value on your own, manually. My solution fits into PDO's `prepare`, yours doesn't. It's obvious, if you take a seconds to assume you might not see everything instantly. It has nothing to do with comparing concatenation between MySQL and PHP.

Comment: @Mjh Why do I need to quote anything manually here and how does this not fit into PDO's prepare? It's using a `?` placeholder, to which PDO will bind the value `%foo%` (no quotes, since it's not a literal, it's just the pure _string value_ `%foo%`). – If PDO is using actual native database parameter binding, no quoting will ever take place, since `%foo%` will be passed as a *separate value* all the way through to the database and quotes are irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, I've changed it to '?' now. I meant could as in that it's possible to set markers an bind values later.

Comment: @deceze - do you really not see the difference between the two? One would think that a person with so much time spent here is able to spot subtle, yet crucial differences. While this answer appears to be working and you took the time to write it, I still find it amusing how you're arguing about something you're missing, yet you still think you're not wrong :) oh well, I guess it happens to everyone from time to time.

Comment: @Mjh If I am so crucially wrong, please spell it out. I am trying to spell out to you why I do not think that I'm wrong. If you see a flaw in that, tell me. From my perspective I can see why you think it might make a difference, but I think that you are wrong about that and I'm trying to tell you why. Attempt to convince me the other way around with concrete facts.

Comment: @Mjh Your move: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513505/binding-a-like-pattern-value-two-different-approaches?noredirect=1#comment58718536_35513505

Comment: @RyanVincent - there is a difference between passing a string to the database versus passing a parameter. With `PDO`, you can't pass parameters wrapped in quotes, example: `WHERE x LIKE '%:search_term%'`. You have to either clean the value of `:parameter` and pass entire string or you can use this syntax: `WHERE x LIKE CONCAT('%', :param, '%');`. That's all there is about it, Fluent might be exposing an interface for the first to work - I really don't know, I use `PDO` so I'm commenting instead of answering since I didn't check Fluent's code.

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm sorry, but I can't seem to find who exactly mentioned security, the term more secure or word "safe". Also I don't really get the animosity displayed over a simple matter, so having said that - I'll excuse myself from further discussion. I believe examples I made state clear my *opinion* on the matter, nothing else.

Comment: @N.B. To clarify: you do understand that the above syntax is equivalent to a PDO `prepare('... LIKE ?')->bindValue(1, '%' . $value . '%')`, right? Then we're just arguing why that is supposedly worse than `... LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')`. To which the answer is: it isn't, and you guys have so far failed to explain exactly why it should be. – This might explain the built up of animosity. Note that the first word on the topic by Mjh was *"the correct way is..."*, which automatically requires some explanation as to why the other way is supposedly *incorrect*.

Comment: @deceze - that's right, I didn't understand that (using Fluent) the example translates into `bindValue(':parameter', '%' . $value .'%');`, which I'm happy to admit - I don't know how fluent deals with that, but the technique I've been using (with PDO) is that I simply use `CONCAT('%', :parameter, '%');` - it's not confusing and it's clear enough, even for developers that see it for the first time. As for which is better and which is worse - I won't go there, some things are best left to personal tastes. If it works like you explained, then I owe you an apology and I'm sorry.

Comment: @RyanVincent - the gist of the whole argument is whether developer passes `%search_term%` to `bindValue` or only `search_term`. `bindValue(1, '%' . $param .'%');` is almost equivalent to `LIKE CONCAT('%', :param, '%');`. The difference is that no one has to worry about wrapping the search term with `%%`. Apparently fluent does it automatically, which I'm completely unfamiliar with since I don't use it, as I mentioned. My *opinion* is that it's easier to read SQL-only syntax, which is eons from being a factual matter. That's all there was to my comment :)

Comment: @N.B. Fluent does not wrap the search term in `%`, no (I'm not using it either, but from scanning the documentation I can't see anything about that). – I can sort of accept your argument for `CONCAT`, but I think it's an extremely minor point, since *somewhere very close to `$searchTerm`* you'll need to write `%`; whether you do that in `CONCAT` inside the query or in PHP while binding is IMO pretty equal. I'd argue for doing it in PHP because that keeps the query cleaner and causes less work for the database (however minuscule that is).

Comment: @N.B, that makes sense. I understand your view point more now. Thanks for explaining.